# Container field clears after clicking accept requires second try to actually capture signature

Tags: ipad, filemaker

I have a Filemaker 16 hosted application to be used with a ipad. Within the application I have a scripted container field which captures a users signature. Once the user has signed the field they click accept, the first time clicking accept the signature window closes and show it was loaded but then the signature window reopens and cleared the field. I am not sure why that would occur.

The field is set as a container and the container is defined as a button.
The script is

`Set Error Capture Off
Insert from device    Type: signature     Presentation: Overlay
Commit Records with dialog off`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are invoking the signatur capture twice. Check that you don’t have a field entry triggering. Best would be to use the debugger if you have FileMaker advanced.

Comment: Awesome, sure was. I had a trigger on field entry and a button.

Answer (score 0):

I've suffered the same issue. I believe it's a bug in FM Go 16 and it was fixed by the latest release (early 2018).